# Saving data from a jquery post into a .net Session variable

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have built a .aspx page that calls a web api service and returns some data. The button in question is an HTML button(non .net) of type "button". I would like to save the data returned (which is a boolean) from the following jquery post:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#custSubmit').click(function () {
            var user = {
                email: $('#custEmail').val(),
                password: $('#custPassword').val()
            };
            $.post("http://blahblah", user, function (data, status) {
                if (data == "true" && status == "success") {
                    //I imagine my save logic will go here, but I could be wrong
                }
                $('#custEmail').val('');
                $('#custPassword').val('');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

but I'm having trouble finding an example of how to save it to a session variable in .net. Can anyone explain to me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sessions are saved on Server. jQuery runs on client machine. You need to save your data where your http://blahblah resides assuming its a web service (bad idea though)

Comment: What do you want to do with this value and why do you want it to be a session?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the data (not security-related), you could store it on the client side in either a cookie or local storage. Local storage is only available if you don't need to support older browsers though.

Comment: Its a boolean that returns true or false depending on if a user's credentials are in a database. Probably not the most secure method, but its mainly for a proof of concept.

Comment: If it needs to be secure, which is what it sounds like, you should perform this check on the server each time rather than attempting to store it on the client.

Comment: I'm trying to do it this way because if the user is validated, the client will redirect to another page with user specific information. Otherwise, the non-validated user will not be able to navigate to that page. Kind of fumbling in the dark as to the best practice for this though.

Comment: A cookie should accomplish what you want and you'll be able to reference in on the server similar to the way that you would check a session variable.